# Возможно ли добавить и выполнить макрос в Excel файле из java-кода?

Tags: java, excel

Возможно ли добавить макрос в Excel файл динамически, с помощью java-кода, и выполнить его так же?

Comment: [Creating Dynamic Macro Enabled Excel by Java](http://javaprogramming.language-tutorial.com/2012/10/creating-dynamic-macro-enabled-excel-by.html)